# Sed only with specific place

Tags: sed

For example;

I'd love to replace **/test** src path only within `<img>` tag.

However `<p>test</p>` should not be touched.

```
$ cat test.html
<img src="/test" width="18" alt="" /><br>
<p>test</p>
```

For now I could execute something like;

```
sed -i '/test'|/hoge|g' test.html
```

However it changes the word globally.

Comment: don't use regex for this, use html parsers like xmlstarlet

Answer (score 0):

`sed '/<img/s|/test|/hoge|g' test.html` would work for one line `<img` tags

Sed allows the `s///g` replacement to be prefixed with another `/PATTERN/` to restrict the replacement to lines matching PATTERN.

But you should really use an xml parser to be safe.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you put some link about the xml parser?

Answer (score 0):

Another approach with sed:

```
sed -i 's|\(<img *src="/\)test|\1hoge|'  test.html
```

`<img *src="/` is captured and backreferenced using `\1` in substitution string.
Following string(`test`) is replaced with `hoge`.